# Performing Image alignment using pyramid levels with semi dense depth

Tags: computer-vision, visual-odometry, monocular

To gain some confidence, I want to implement the camera tracking (optimization problem) discussed in [Semi Dense Visual Odometry for a monocular camera](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_iccv_2013/papers/Engel_Semi-dense_Visual_Odometry_2013_ICCV_paper.pdf)<sup>J Engel, J Strum, D Cremers</sup>

$$E(\xi) = \underset{i}\Sigma\frac{\alpha(r_i(\xi))}{\sigma_{d_i}^2}(r_i(\xi))$$
$$r_i(\xi) = (I_2(w(x_i, d_i, \xi)) - I_1(x_i))$$

Using Gauss-Newton method, as discussed in the same paper, (local optima) $\xi$ between two monocular images can be found. Here is how I think the process goes:

**Given**

- Start with initial guess $\xi_0$ (~ 0), Images $I_1, I_2$, Depth for some points in image $I_1$ is given

**Steps**

- Start at lowest level (most coarse) $L_n$ pyramid image (same as shrinked image?) and corresponding depth map (for points in shrinked image?)
- Gauss Newton iterations with some library (I plan to use python for ease).

  - Setup the residual calculation function that takes input $I_2$, $I_1$, {$x_i$}, {$d_i$} and {$\xi$} and produces $r_i$. The Jacobian involved will be calculated numerically.
  - I can skip $\alpha(.)$ and $\sigma_{d_i}^2$ for now. $E(\xi) = \underset{i}\Sigma ~r_i^2$
  - At the end I expect to get the result $\xi_L$
- Use the solution $\xi_L$ as initial guess and repeat for the next pyramid level (**n-1**)

Questions:

- Am I missing some step in above process ? Please let me know.
- Is there a library function in openCV that take an image (and its depth image) as input and give in output the requested pyramid level (for a choosen **n**) image as output (depth image will also need to be shrinked)?

PS: can someone with higher reputation add the tag "Image-alignment" to this question?

Comment: Wow blows me away that this question was asked over a year ago and you're putting a bounty on it now. Good luck! I tried to add an image-alignment tag but [no such tag exists](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: @Chuck Yeah :)  I was trying to do this a year back and then left it midway. I think I can implement a crude solution as outlined above but then I feel like there is a better way of doing this. I hope the bounty helps.  About the tag, I was referring to creating a new tag **image-alignment**.

Comment: For tag creation, please start a "New tag request: image-alignment" question at the [meta site](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer this question but please don't flame me if I got something wrong. Those were two heavy papers and I didn't have as much time as I wish to go through them.

---

The pyramids are the same as shrank image indeed. Image pyramids are images with lower resolution. As a general concept, by reducing the resolution and representing a different amount of details, the tracking algorithm can focus on different types of feature and become more generic. See [pyrUp/Down](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d1f/tutorial_pyramids.html) in OpenCV.

---

It is a little hard to answer because it is not clear what is the granularity of your question.

I feel like the general steps of the algorithm are there but if I have the time later, I'll go through it again later. However, Gaussian-Newton optimization are rarely plug and play for me, so I would be cautious there in there of the time needed to have it running.

I'm wondering if, since you'll be ignoring $\alpha$ and $\sigma^2_{d_{i}}$ You're not implementing the method of **Steinbrücker et al.** in *Real-Time Visual Odometry from Dense RGB-D Images* (full disclaimer I didn't have time to read this one in details just skimmed it).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for adding this answer. It is really helpful (I'm looking into the pyrUP/DOWN). I see that the other part of the Question (about the correctness of given implementation) might seem unclear, essentially I wanted to implement the IA algorithm correctly. There are many projects that do this (IA) and I thought someone with experience might validate the outlined steps for performing IA.